# Using python to convert xml input file to selected element csv output file

Tags: python, csv

I have started to use python to convert an xml file as an input to a csv output file that contains selected elements from the xml file.

this is my input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Awards>
 <Header>
<FinAssType>LWA</FinAssType>
<FileType>Awards</FileType>
<ExtractDateTime>2019-09-09T14:00:21.050</ExtractDateTime>
<LACode>350</LACode>
<OrganisationName>BogusName Council</OrganisationName>
<SupplierDetails>
  <SupplierID>2</SupplierID>
  <SupplierName>Paypoint</SupplierName>
</SupplierDetails>
</Header>
<AwardRecords>
   <CaseIdentification>
     <CaseReference>LWA143211</CaseReference>
  <DateOfApplication>2019-09-04</DateOfApplication>
  <ReasonForApplication>A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit/Income Spent</ReasonForApplication>
</CaseIdentification>
<ApplicantDetails>
  <ApplicantTitle>Miss</ApplicantTitle>
  <ApplicantForename>Poor</ApplicantForename>
  <ApplicantSurname>Soul1</ApplicantSurname>
  <ApplicantNINO>BogusNI</ApplicantNINO>
  <DateOfBirth>1964-01-01</DateOfBirth>
  <ApplicantAddress1>6 Brick Lane </ApplicantAddress1>
  <ApplicantAddress2>BogusTown </ApplicantAddress2>
  <ApplicantAddress3 />
  <ApplicantAddress4 />
  <ApplicantPostcode>AA4 BB5</ApplicantPostcode>
  <ApplicantTelNo>0777777773</ApplicantTelNo>
  <ApplicantEmail />
  <DateMovedIn>2019-07-29</DateMovedIn>
</ApplicantDetails>
   <ClaimDetails>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>262369</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Essential food items</AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Food</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>40.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-09-06T15:18:19.827</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>44.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>44.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777773</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus Two</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
</ClaimDetails>
</AwardRecords>
 <AwardRecords>
    <CaseIdentification>
    <CaseReference>LWA143385</CaseReference>
     <DateOfApplication>2019-09-06</DateOfApplication>
  <ReasonForApplication>A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction</ReasonForApplication>
</CaseIdentification>
<ApplicantDetails>
  <ApplicantTitle>Mr</ApplicantTitle>
  <ApplicantForename>Poor2</ApplicantForename>
  <ApplicantSurname>Soul2</ApplicantSurname>
  <ApplicantNINO>BogusNI</ApplicantNINO>
  <DateOfBirth>1980-01-01</DateOfBirth>
  <ApplicantAddress1>Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  </ApplicantAddress1>
  <ApplicantAddress2 />
  <ApplicantAddress3 />
  <ApplicantAddress4 />
  <ApplicantPostcode>AA2 BB3</ApplicantPostcode>
  <ApplicantTelNo>0777777772</ApplicantTelNo>
  <ApplicantEmail />
  <DateMovedIn>2019-07-01</DateMovedIn>
</ApplicantDetails>
<ClaimDetails>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>262680</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation </AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Gas</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>30.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-09-06T14:10:39.857</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>20.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>20.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777772</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus One</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>262681</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation </AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Electricity</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>30.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-09-06T14:10:39.873</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>20.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>20.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777772</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus One</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>262682</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Essential food items</AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Food</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>40.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-09-06T14:10:39.920</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>40.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>40.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777772</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus One</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>262683</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Please provide details</AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Nappies, toiletries and household products</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>10.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>10</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-09-06T14:10:39.937</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>8.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>8.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777772</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus One</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
</ClaimDetails>
  </AwardRecords>
   <AwardRecords>
<CaseIdentification>
  <CaseReference>LWA145416</CaseReference>
  <DateOfApplication>2019-10-07</DateOfApplication>
  <ReasonForApplication>A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Other emergency – please specify below</ReasonForApplication>
</CaseIdentification>
<ApplicantDetails>
  <ApplicantTitle>Mr</ApplicantTitle>
  <ApplicantForename>Poor3</ApplicantForename>
  <ApplicantSurname>Soul3</ApplicantSurname>
  <ApplicantNINO>BogusNI</ApplicantNINO>
  <DateOfBirth>1995-01-01</DateOfBirth>
  <ApplicantAddress1>64A Broomlands Street</ApplicantAddress1>
  <ApplicantAddress2>BogusTown</ApplicantAddress2>
  <ApplicantAddress3 />
  <ApplicantAddress4 />
  <ApplicantPostcode>AA BB2</ApplicantPostcode>
  <ApplicantTelNo>0777777771</ApplicantTelNo>
  <ApplicantEmail />
  <DateMovedIn>2012-10-17</DateMovedIn>
</ApplicantDetails>
<ClaimDetails>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>266130</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Essential food items</AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Food</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>80.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-10-08T09:22:45.577</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>30.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>30.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777771</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus One</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
  <Claim>
    <ItemRequested>
      <ClaimID>266131</ClaimID>
      <AssistanceType>Please provide details</AssistanceType>
      <GoodsType>Nappies, toiletries and household products</GoodsType>
      <AmountRequested>13.00</AmountRequested>
      <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    </ItemRequested>
    <AwardDetail>
      <AwardDate>2019-10-08T09:22:45.577</AwardDate>
      <AwardValue>2.00</AwardValue>
      <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
      <TotalAwardValue>2.00</TotalAwardValue>
      <PaymentType>Paypoint SMS</PaymentType>
      <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
      <Reference1Name>Confirm Mobile number</Reference1Name>
      <Reference1Value>0777777771</Reference1Value>
      <Reference2Name>Name of decison maker making award</Reference2Name>
      <Reference2Value>Bogus One</Reference2Value>
      <Reference3Value />
      <Reference4Value />
      <Reference5Value />
    </AwardDetail>
  </Claim>
   </ClaimDetails>
  </AwardRecords>
   <Trailer>
    <NoOfRecords>16</NoOfRecords>
    <TotalOfAwardValues>1124.00</TotalOfAwardValues>
   </Trailer>
```

this is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("h:/scripting/python/XML/input/mytest.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

csv_data = open('h:\scripting\python\XML\output\mytest.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_data)
head =  ['CaseReference','DateOfApplication','ReasonForApplication','ApplicantTitle','ApplicantSurname','DateOfBirth','Address1','Address2','PostCode','TelNun','ClaimID','AssistanceType','GoodsType','Quantity','AwardValue','PaymentType']

csvwriter.writerow(head)

for child in root:
row = []
#print (child.tag,child.attrib)
#going down into AwardRecords tag
if child.tag == "AwardRecords":
    #print(child[0].tag)
    for step_child in child:
        if step_child.tag == "CaseIdentification":
            caseref = step_child.find('CaseReference').text
            casedate = step_child.find('DateOfApplication').text
            casereason = step_child.find  ('ReasonForApplication').text
            row.append(caseref)
            row.append(casedate)
            row.append(casereason)
 ######################################################
        if step_child.tag == "ApplicantDetails":
            apptitle = step_child.find('ApplicantTitle').text
            appfore = step_child.find('ApplicantForename').text
            appsur = step_child.find('ApplicantSurname').text
            appnino = step_child.find('ApplicantNINO').text
            appdob = step_child.find('DateOfBirth').text
            appadd1 = step_child.find('ApplicantAddress1').text
            appadd2 = step_child.find('ApplicantAddress2').text
            apppostc = step_child.find('ApplicantPostcode').text
            apptel = step_child.find('ApplicantTelNo').text
            appdatemove = step_child.find('DateMovedIn').text
            row.append(apptitle)
            #row.append(appfore)
            row.append(appsur)
            #row.append(appnino)
            row.append(appdob)
            row.append(appadd1)
            row.append(appadd2)
            row.append(apppostc)
            row.append(apptel)
            #row.append(appdatemove)

            # drop into ClaimDetails element
        if step_child.tag == "ClaimDetails":
                claimcount=0
                for step_child2 in step_child:
                    #print(step_child2.tag)
                    if step_child2.tag == "Claim":


                        for step_child3 in step_child2:
                            #print(step_child3.tag)
                            if step_child3.tag == "ItemRequested":
                                claimid = step_child3.find('ClaimID').text
                                assistancetype = step_child3.find('AssistanceType').text
                                goodstype = step_child3.find('GoodsType').text
                                itemquantity = step_child3.find('ItemQuantity').text
                                row.append(claimid)
                                row.append(assistancetype)
                                row.append(goodstype)
                                row.append(itemquantity)

                            if step_child3.tag == "AwardDetail":
                                awarddate = step_child3.find('AwardDate').text
                                awardvalue = step_child3.find`('AwardValue').text
                                awardtotal  = step_child3.find`('TotalAwardValue').text
                                paymenttype  = step_child3.find`('PaymentType').text
                                #row.append(awarddate)
                                row.append(awardvalue)
                                #row.append(awardtotal)
                                row.append(paymenttype)
                                csvwriter.writerow(row)

csv_data.close()
```

this is my actual output

```
   `CaseReference,DateOfApplication,ReasonForApplication,ApplicantTitle,ApplicantSurname,DateOfBirth,Address1,Address2,PostCode,TelNun,ClaimID,AssistanceType,GoodsType,Quantity,AwardValue,PaymentType

`LWA143211,2019-09-04,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit/Income Spent,Miss,Soul1,1964-01-01,6 Brick Lane ,BogusTown ,AA4 BB5,0777777773,262369,Essential food items,Food,1,44.00,Paypoint SMS

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit       Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262680,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Gas,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262680,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Gas,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS,262681,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Electricity,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262680,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Gas,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS,262681,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Electricity,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS,262682,Essential food items,Food,1,40.00,Paypoint SMS

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262680,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Gas,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS,262681,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Electricity,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS,262682,Essential food items,Food,1,40.00,Paypoint SMS,262683,Please provide details,"Nappies, toiletries and household products",10,8.00,Paypoint SMS

`LWA145416,2019-10-07,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Other emergency – please specify below,Mr,Soul3,1995-01-01,64A Broomlands Street,BogusTown,AA BB2,0777777771,266130,Essential food items,Food,1,30.00,Paypoint SMS

`LWA145416,2019-10-07,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Other emergency – please specify below,Mr,Soul3,1995-01-01,64A Broomlands Street,BogusTown,AA BB2,0777777771,266130,Essential food items,Food,1,30.00,Paypoint SMS,266131,Please provide details,"Nappies, toiletries and household products",1,2.00,Paypoint SMS`
```

my desired output is
                `CaseReference,DateOfApplication,ReasonForApplication,ApplicantTitle,ApplicantSurname,DateOfBirth,Address1,Address2,PostCode,TelNun,ClaimID,AssistanceType,GoodsType,Quantity,AwardValue,PaymentType`

`LWA143211,2019-09-04,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit/Income Spent,Miss,Soul1,1964-01-01,6 Brick Lane ,BogusTown ,AA4 BB5,0777777773,262369,Essential food items,Food,1,44.00,Paypoint SMS`

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262680,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Gas,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS`

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262681,Gas or Electricity. May also cover connection/installation ,Electricity,1,20.00,Paypoint SMS`

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262682,Essential food items,Food,1,40.00,Paypoint SMS`

`LWA143385,2019-09-06,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Benefit Sanction,Mr,Soul2,1980-01-01,Flat G/1 1 Teviot Avenue BogusTown  ,,AA2 BB3,0777777772,262683,Please provide details,"Nappies, toiletries and household products",10,8.00,Paypoint SMS`

`LWA145416,2019-10-07,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Other emergency – please specify below,Mr,Soul3,1995-01-01,64A Broomlands Street,BogusTown,AA BB2,0777777771,266130,Essential food items,Food,1,30.00,Paypoint SMS`

```
`LWA145416,2019-10-07,A - Crisis Grant - Emergency~Other emergency – please specify below,Mr,Soul3,1995-01-01,64A Broomlands Street,BogusTown,AA BB2,0777777771,266131,Please provide details,"Nappies, toiletries and household products",1,2.00,Paypoint SMS`
```

You can see that the issue is when there are more than one claim per case reference within the the claimdetails element. My current code appends the claim to the end of the line, rather than creating a new line (I can see that the loop does this).
Can anyone assist how I would "know" how many claims existed to create a new line for each one.

Sorry that the question is so code and input/output heavy

Any assistance to help solve this would be much appreciated

cheers

Smudger

I have done this on a windows install with python 3.7, using pycharm with idea of transferring code to Linux box when I am satisfied with output

Answer (score 0):

In your original API request URL string, see if you can add a parameter "$format=json".

I've used various APIs from SAP, for example, and the default response is in XML, but if you pass the "$format=json", then the response changes to json … which is easy to convert to dictionary in python using .json() method.

Then once it's a dictionary, easy to convert into a dataframe directly using pd.Dataframe(your_dict_converted) … or if there are embedded lists you can use pd.Datarame.from_records(your_dict_converted).

Converting from dataframe to CSV  with .to_csv().